# How could I generate a list of <p>'s from an array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

How do I generate a list of `<p>'s` from an array with HTML and using JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This?

```
var i, p;

for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   p = document.createElement('p');
   p.innerHTML = array[i];
   document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enclose the html content into paragraph maybe you can do it with an oneliner:

```
var resulting_html = '<p>' + content_array.join('</p><p>') + '</p>';
```

assuming that the array containing the html is called content_array.
You will have the html ready to incorporate it into the target element.